# How can I hang a picture?

Tags: walls

I tried to hang pictures on the wall using Command™ no mess picture hangers. I cleaned the walls as the instruction requested, then applied the Command™picture hanger and let it set. When I hung the picture, they fell off the wall. How can you hang pictures on an oil base painted walls?

Comment: What material is the wall itself, any restriction on using nail based picture hangers?

Comment: There are several different Command picture hangers. The one I checked is rated for 8 pounds max. If the framed picture's weight is more, it won't hold.

Answer (score 3):

How about a good old fashioned nail and a picture hanger? Don't think I've ever had one of those fall down.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the pictures that you want to hang are relatively light weight and the wall at the hanging site is hollow (i.e. free of a stud obstruction) then you may want to consider one of the newer style wire hanger hooks.

[image]

These are very easy to install simply by poking the long sharp end straight into the wall. You push it in to the bend just behind the hook. The long end of the strong spring wire presses against the inside surface of the drywall. One of these can easily hold up to 30 pounds or so. (Some manufacturers of these claim greater capacity but I would limit the usage to light weight pictures and kick-nack items.

One brand name to look for is Monkey Hook.